# concatenate matrix to another matrix

Tags: matlab, image-processing, matrix, rgb, reshape

I wrote a matlab code that reads images from folder(images are in RGB). 
It reads the image one by one. After reading the first image it re-sizes it and then reshapes it so that the new image dimension is (any number of rows X 3 volumes) using this function:

`Vectrgb = reshape(rgb,[],3);`

Then the code will read a new image.

How should I append  the matrix of the second image to the one?

Below is the code:

```
Folder = 'fo\';
Files  = dir([Folder, '\*.png']);
Y=[];
for i = 1 : length(Folder) 
name  = strcat('telo-phase\',Files(i).name);
image = imread(name);
rgb   = imresize(image, 0.50); % resize the image  
Vectrgb = reshape(rgb,[],3);
end
Vectrgb1 = Vectrgb';[ind2,ctrs2]= kmeans(double(Vectrgb1),2);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wat `Y` to be the concatanation of all RGB vectors of all images you need to add this line inside the loop

```
   Y = cat( 1, Y, Vecrgb );
```

PS,
When dealing with filenames and paths it is a good practice to use `fullfile` command:

```
Files = dir( fullfile( Folder, '*.png' ) );
```

Makes your code platform independent.